# I'm sick and throwing up all over the place, what do I do?

Tags: below

Here's the story, I was journeying down below and finding many new things to scarf on. I'm finding turnips, morsels, chops, it's a *smorgasbord* down there. I eventually came across some innards and gave that a try. Boy was that a ***mistake***. I became *sick* the moment it hit my tongue. I was throwing up all over the place, it was hard to move around. And with creatures swarming me and attacking me, I barely made it out alive!

I was like that for 30 seconds to a minute but it felt like it was for hours, maybe *days*. I tried drinking water and eating some food but it didn't help at all. I just hid in a corner healing my wounds until I recovered.

But I didn't like that feeling, I don't ever want to feel like that again, so **no** more innards for me! But if I see another one down there, I can't guarantee that I've learned my lesson and I might just forget and eat it since it looks so good...

If that ever happens again, what can I do to heal myself of being sick sooner?